# Migration Master pages from SharePoint 2007 to 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, master-pages

I have seen many posts about people migrating Master Pages from 2007 to 2010 but I'm more interested in knowing more about problems faced at development level. I am planning to migration Master pages for publishing sites to SharePoint 2010.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best option is probably to edit the 2010 master page to look like your custom master page rather than trying to modify the existing custom code - customisations tend to be simpler than the SharePoint page structure and easily pasted into the new master page.

How hard it will be depends on how closely your design matches the default SharePoint page structure - getting the ribbon to work within a fixed width layout takes far more work than it should.

Answer (score 0):

There is MSDN article on this topic:

Upgrading an Existing Master Page to the SharePoint Foundation Master Page
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee539981(office.14).aspx

Answer (score 0):

If the master page that is to be updated was designed using the Microsoft supported customizations, then there should be no problem in upgrading the master page.